# Twilio autopilot whatsapp initiate a conversation to a phone using nodeJS

Tags: node.js, twilio, whatsapp, twilio-node

I created a Autopilot bot in console of Twilio. I need to publish that bot to multiple phone numbers from an nodeJS endpoint.
My questions are :

1. How do i send the actions from an nodeJS app to initiate the conversation ?
2. Can i send the bot to different numbers from that nodeJS app and get the individual responses as an callback.

Comment: What do you mean "send publish"?

Comment: Sorry typo, that is send only, will edit it.

Answer (score 1):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

You can initiate a message with the bot using the Twilio REST API in the programming language of your choosing, like JavaScript, C#, PHP, Ruby, Python, or Java.

```
curl -X POST https://api.twilio.com/2010-04-01/Accounts/ACXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX/Messages.json \
--data-urlencode "Body=Hi there!" \
--data-urlencode "From=REPLACE-WITH-YOUR-TWILIO-NUMBER" \
--data-urlencode "To=+NUMBER-TO-TEXT" \
-u ACXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX:your_auth_token
```

This cURL request initiates an outbound SMS. Then if you configure the Twilio number to an Autopilot bot, when the user responds, they will enter in to the bot dialogue.

You can publish the bot to multiple numbers either in the [phone number console](https://www.twilio.com/console/phone-numbers/incoming) for each number and get the responses in the [Autopilot request](https://www.twilio.com/docs/autopilot/actions/autopilot-request) like with Memory.

Comment: Thanks for response. I want to initiate an autopilot, not send an message. Can i do that from an nodeJS app?

Comment: Where Autopilot initiates the message? I don't understand the difference between initiating an autopilot session and Autopilot sending the first message

Comment: I want to initiate the autopilot session

Comment: What will happen once the autopilot session is initiated?